# Does the total energy in an electromagnetic field depend on the acceleration of the sources?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

If I accelerate a charge from rest to some velocity $\vec v$, does the total final electromagnetic energy contained in the field depend upon the acceleration of the charge?

Comment: Why do you think it could depend on that?

Comment: You need to make some additional assumptions to get definite answer. Is the charge concentrated at a point, or is there finite charge density everywhere? How is the charge accelerated? What is the state of the EM field when the acceleration begins?

Comment: trying to parse the question @Physiks lover may be asking about the energy of the radiated field of an accelerated charge.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm trying to understand where the self-force for an accelerated charge comes from. Since the self-force increases with acceleration I thought this might be because more electromagnetic energy is created.

Comment: @Physikslover - Accelerated charged particles radiate photons in addition to the electromagnetic fields they produce.  Is that to what you were referring?  The emission of radiation does mean that more input energy is needed to accelerate particles to higher energies.